# UnprojectedPropertyError in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

The following is a working code in google app engine. This is used to display some records from a SentMail Model. The SentMail have a large no of fields, here i only showed the fields we now need. Since for displaying data i do not require to take the complete record. Hence i used projection. Note: This code is working

```
class SentMail(ndb.Model):
to_email = ndb.StringProperty()
bounced = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)
bounce_type = ndb.StringProperty()
bounceSubType = ndb.StringProperty()

@staticmethod
def get_bounced_emails():
    db_query = SentMail.query(SentMail.bounced==True, projection=['to_email', 'bounce_type'], distinct=True).order(SentMail.bounce_type).order(SentMail.to_email).fetch()
    return db_query if len(db_query) > 0 else None




class BounceCompaintRender(session_module.BaseSessionHandler):
"""docstring for BounceCompaintRender"""
def get(self):
        bounced_emails = self.get_data('complete_bounced_rec')

        template_values = {
            'bounced_emails': bounced_emails

        }

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/bounce_complaint_emails.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
    else:
        self.redirect('/login')

def get_data(self, key):
    data = memcache.get(key)
    if data is not None:
        for each in data:
            logging.info(each)
        return data
    else:
        data = SentMail.get_bounced_emails()
        memcache.add(key="complete_bounced_rec", value=data, time=3600)
        return data
```

Here the only change I made is in SentMail.get_bounced_emails()

```
@staticmethod
def get_bounced_emails():
    db_query = SentMail.query(SentMail.bounced==True, projection=['to_email', 'bounceSubType'], distinct=True).order(SentMail.bounceSubType).order(SentMail.to_email).fetch()
    return db_query if len(db_query) > 0 else None
```

I now get an error **UnprojectedPropertyError: Property bounceSubType is not in the projection**. I checked the logs and i found in the projection field one parameter is missing and eventhough it has a value None(None is not the only value). I tried clearing memcache but the problem still arises. The following is the log

```
SentMail(key=Key('SentMail', 655553213235462), bounceSubType=None, to_email=u'test@example.com', _projection=('to_email',))
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if that was it, since you didn't declare it as an unindexed property, but is bounceSubType indexed or not?

Comment: i did not set any indexing property, which would mean it has to be indexed right. Anyway since you mentioned i specifically set indexed=True, but then im still with no luck. This updated code is in a different version, so i have made the necessary entries into the index.yaml as well to generate the indexes for google app engine. The indexes are also getting generated. Is there anything i could be missing?

Comment: could this be a problem with the memcache because when the memcache is cleared, the updated code actually works once, and when on reload it checks if the key in memcache and generates the error.

Comment: could be, but your projection query doesn't hit the memcache, except with ndb.  I know ndb uses the memcache, but there should be internal controls to make sure it actually polls if the memcache is empty.  I'll try to reproduce your issue and see what I can come up with

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the difference in the model SentMail wrote in `models.py` and in datastore (i.e., properties are different in both). For this you need to update all records in datastore related to SentMail then datastore and model will have the same fields.